# get value from two dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**Code**

```
$two[0][0]=100;
$two[1][0]=110;
$two[2][0]=120;

var_dump($two);

echo "<br> two[0][0]=$two[0][0]";
echo "<br> two[1][0]=$two[1].0";
echo "<br> two[2][0]=$two[2]";
```

**Output**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 100
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 110
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 120

( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion 

two[0][0]=Array[0]
two[1][0]=Array.0
two[2][0]=Array
```

How to get the value from this two-dimensional array ? I was able to use get output for single dimension array using `echo $single[1]`

Comment: try `echo "<br> two[0][0]=" . $two[0][0];` or `echo "<br> two[0][0]={$two[0][0]}";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use `echo "<br> two[0][0]=$two[0][0]";`

it read as `$two[0]. "[0]"` which return output as `Array[0]`

Try

```
echo "<br> two[0][0]=" . $two[0][0];
```

or

```
echo "<br> two[0][0]={$two[0][0]}";
```

---

Change your code as

```
$two[0][0]=100;
$two[1][0]=110;
$two[2][0]=120;

var_dump($two);

echo "<br> two[0][0]={$two[0][0]}";
echo "<br> two[1][0]={$two[1][0]}";
echo "<br> two[2][0]={$two[2][0]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this way,

```
$two[0][0]=100;
$two[1][0]=110;
$two[2][0]=120;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($two);
echo "</pre>";

echo "\n";
//concatenate your 2d array with string here
echo "two[0][0]=".$two[0][0]."\n"; 
echo "two[1][0]=".$two[1][0]."\n";
echo "two[2][0]=".$two[2][0]."\n";
```